# how can I show item that matches barcode number from table?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

(sorry for the change) Im using korean in the table but when I use this php file the output comes as ??? I want to show out put in korean as same as the table not ??? how should i change it?

```
   <?php

       DEFINE ('DBUSER', 'root');
       DEFINE ('DBPW', '****');
       DEFINE ('DBHOST', 'locashost');
       DEFINE ('DBNAME', 'shopping');

       header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8");

       $dbc = mysqli_connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPW);
       if (!$dbc) {
           die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
           exit();
       }

       $dbs = mysqli_select_db($dbc, DBNAME);
       if (!$dbs) {
           die("Database selection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
           exit();
       }

    #   mysql_query("set session character_set_connection=utf8;");
    #   mysql_query("set session character_set_results=utf8;");
    #   mysql_query("set session character_set_client=utf8;");

            $barcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_GET['barcode']); 
       $result = mysqli_query($dbc, "SHOW COLUMNS FROM product");
       $numberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
       if ($numberOfRows > 0) 
       {

       $values = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT * FROM product WHERE barcode=$barcode");
       while ($rowr = mysqli_fetch_row($values)) {
        for ($j=0;$j<$numberOfRows;$j++) {
         $csv_output .= $rowr[$j].", ";
        }
        $csv_output .= "\n";
       }

       }

       print $csv_output;
       exit;
    ?>
```

Comment: `"how should i change the php file?"` - That depends on what the problem is.  Which is what, exactly?

Comment: I apologize for changing the question how should I fix it if i want the output to come out as normal when using foreign language?